# Does Mithral Armor in the form of a Chain Shirt still count as a light armor?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, armor

Does Mithral Armor in the form of a Chain Shirt still count as a light armor?
I remember in 3.5 and Pathfinder it counted as light armor so Rogues could then use it;  and often sought out the armor..

Comment: You may be interested in Elven Chain, which is a different magic item which is a chain shirt which does consider you to be proficient even if you lack proficiency in medium armour (but it is still medium armour).

Comment: In 3.5 and Pathfinder Chain Shirt is a light armor regardles of material. You may have meant Elven Chain which is described in 3.5 as a special sort of Chainmail made of Mithral and considered light armor while regular Chainmail is a medium armor.

Comment: @Ols Specifically, mithral does make armor one stage lighter in 3.5. Armor can however never be lighter than light, and as you say the chain shirt is light by default.

Comment: @WeckarE. Absolutely right. Elven Chain is just a Mithral Chainmail, but it is also described separatly in the magic items section with a specific name (Elven Chain). I suspect this can be the source of confusion.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### No, the armor's category does not change.

> Mithral Armor
>
> Armor (medium or heavy, but not hide), uncommon
>
> Mithral is a light, flexible metal. A mithral chain shirt or breastplate can be worn under normal clothes. If the armor normally imposes disadvantage on Dexterity (Stealth) checks or has a Strength requirement, the mithral version of the armor doesn't.
>
> (DMG, p. 182)